# Can a non-aggregate class be a POD class C++

Tags: c++

From what I know if a class is not an aggregate then it is sure not a POD.

However in the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class NotAggregate2
{
  int x; //x is private by default and non-static 
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << std::is_pod<NotAggregate2>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_aggregate <NotAggregate2>::value << '\n';
}
```

which have output:

```
true
false
```

NotAggregate2 is not aggregate but a POD type.

So can a non-aggregate class be a POD class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prior to C++11, you'd be correct: [POD classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#POD_class) needed to be [aggregate types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Definitions), which in turn could not have private non-static data members. Post-C++11 however, POD types which are classes no longer need to be aggregates. Rather, POD types just need to satisfy the looser requirements of:

1. Being a [standard layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType), which only requires that all non-static data members have the *same* access control, not necessarily public
2. Being a [trivial type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType)
3. For [class types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#POD_class), having no non-POD non-static data members (or arrays thereof)

In C++20, `std::is_pod` and the POD concept have been deprecated in favor of finer-grain properties and their tests, such as `std::is_standard_layout`, `std::is_trivial`, `std::is_trivially_copyable`, and `std::is_aggregate`.